# Unable To Login With Correct Credentials?

Tags: errors

Me and my users can't login even using the correct credentials. We type in the correct username and password but then this error message comes up (it's been coming up for a while now, but I usually just ignore it press the backspace and I'm logged in):

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string in /hermes/bosoraweb097/b2086/ipg.mysite.com1/wp-content/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/wp-customer-reviews.php on line 241

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get back into my account?

Comment: This error is related to the plugin `WP Customer Reviews` just disable it and see.

Comment: I can't deactivate it because I can't log in as I mentioned.

Comment: If you can't get into admin, delete the plugin via FTP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot access the WordPress Dashboard with your user account you will need to use FTP or SSH to access the `wp-content/plugins` directory for your site and rename the plugin folder for `wp-customer-reviews`.

Example:
`wp-content/plugins/wp-customer-reviews` 
becomes
`wp-content/plugins/wp-customer-reviews-broken`

This will disable the plugin and allow you to log into the WP Dashboard again.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error; at least one issue is the WP Customer Reviews plugin. Deactivate it and try logging in again.

**If you can't get into admin, delete the plugin via FTP**

If that doesn't help, see the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

Comment: I can't deactivate it because I can't log in as I mentioned.

Comment: If you can't get into admin, delete the plugin via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the plugin folder name just by adding one letter deactivates the plugin. Login via FTP and change folder name.